# how to overload an assignment operator in swift

Tags: swift, operator-overloading

I would like to override the '=' operator for a CGFloat like the follow try :

```
func = (inout left: CGFloat, right: Float) {
    left=CGFloat(right)
}
```

So I could do the following:

```
var A:CGFloat=1
var B:Float=2
A=B
```

Can this be done ? I get the error `Explicitly discard the result of the closure by assigning to '_'`

Comment: You cannot overload the assignment operator - only compound assignment (like `+=` etc.)

Comment: @Antonio is right, here is the reference for it: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That's not possible - as outlined in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID44):

> It is not possible to overload the default assignment operator (=). Only the compound assignment operators can be overloaded. Similarly, the ternary conditional operator (a ? b : c) cannot be overloaded.

If that doesn't convince you, just change the operator to `+=`:

```
func +=(left: inout CGFloat, right: Float) {
    left += CGFloat(right)
}
```

and you'll notice that you will no longer get a compilation error.

The reason for the misleading error message is probably because the compiler is interpreting your attempt to overload as an assignment

Answer (score 12):

You can not override assignment but you can use different operators in your case. For example `&=` operator.

```
func &= (inout left: CGFloat, right: Float) {
    left = CGFloat(right)
}
```

So you could do the following:

```
var A: CGFLoat = 1
var B: Float = 2
A &= B
```

By the way operators `&+`, `&-`, `&*` exist in swift. They represent C-style operation without overflow. [More](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is **NOT** `operator overload` approach. But the result may be what you are expecting

```
// Conform to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` and implement it
extension String: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    public init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        // String has an initializer that takes an Int, we can use that to
        // create a string
        self = String(value)
    }
}

extension Int: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    public init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self = Int(value) ?? 0
    }
}

// No error, s2 is the string "4"
let s1: Int = "1"
let s2: String = 2

print(s1)       //output: 1
print(s2)       //output: 2
print(s1 + 2)   //output: 3 instead of "12"
```