# Alternative to overloading the assignment operator in Swift

Tags: string, swift, operator-overloading

I'm making a String struct (called `ScalarString`) from scratch that internally is an array of `UInt32` Unicode scalar values (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272561/working-with-unicode-code-points-in-swift) for background).

For a normal Swift `String` I can do the following:

```
let myString: String = "hello"
```

I would like to do

```
let myScalarString: ScalarString = "hello"
```

where I [overload](http://www.raywenderlich.com/80818/operator-overloading-in-swift-tutorial) the assignment [operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html) to convert the "hello" `String` automatically to `ScalarString` behind the scenes. However, [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964177/how-to-overload-an-assignment-operator-in-swift) tells me that is not possible.

I could write a method like

```
myScalarString.set("hello")
```

but that isn't as readable as the assignment operator. Is there any alternative?

```
myScalarString = "hello"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make an assignment

```
let myScalarString: ScalarString = "hello"
```

work with a *string literal* on the right-hand side, it suffices
that you implement the `StringLiteralConvertible` for your type:

```
extension ScalarString : StringLiteralConvertible {

    init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(value)
    }

    init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(value)
    }

    init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(value)
    }
}
```

However, this works only for string literals, not for arbitrary strings,
so this would not compile:

```
let str = "hello"
let yourScalarString: ScalarString = str
```

because (as you already noticed) you cannot overload the assignment
operator, and you would have to use your init method explicitly:

```
let yourScalarString = ScalarString(str)
```

---

In the same manner, you could create a value of your type
from a literal array of Unicode values

```
let myScalarString: ScalarString = [ 65, 66, 67 ]
```

by implementing the `ArrayLiteralConvertible` protocol:

```
extension ScalarString : ArrayLiteralConvertible {
    init(arrayLiteral elements: UInt32...) {
        self.init(elements)
    }

}
```

Comment: So this allows one to make an assignment to a string (or array) literal (not a variable) during initialization only, correct? That is, I couldn't do something like `let myString = ScalarString()` to initialize an empty string and then later set the value with `myString = "hello"`.

Comment: And if my statement above is correct, what is the special magic that Swift does to give this functionality to its own `String` struct?

Comment: @Suragch: `var myString = ScalarString() ; ... ; myString = "hello"` should be possible with the above extensions. – The Swift compiler can do many things that we cannot to (e.g. automatic conversion of Int, Double, String etc to NSObject if necessary).